# unlock user using excel VBA or javascript

Tags: javascript, shell, unix, unlock

I am very new to javascript. I want each user to be able to unlock themselves in UNIX from browser.

The idea is that `$username` will be accepted from HTML and pass to javascript to run:

```
ssh server1 -l user02 /utils/unlock.csh $username
```

The html/javascript am using:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function executeCommands(inputparms)
   {
  // Instantiate the Shell object and invoke its execute method.

    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

    var commandtoRun = "<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function executeCommands(inputparms)
   {
  // Instantiate the Shell object and invoke its execute method.

    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

    var commandtoRun = "ssh server1 -l user02 /utils/unlock.csh $username";
    if (inputparms != "")
     {
      var commandParms = document.Form1.filename.value;
     }

 // Invoke the execute method.  
     oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, 
      "", "open", "1");
  }
</SCRIPT>

<FORM name="Form1">
<CENTER>
<BR><BR>
<H1>Unlock Your Account </H1>
<BR><BR> 
Username:   <Input type="text" name="username"/>
<BR><BR>
<Input type="Button" name="Button1" value="Unlock" onClick="executeCommands()"  />
<BR><BR>

</CENTER>
</BODY>
</FORM>
</HTML>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You've added code to your question, but it is still unclear. Does your current code work? What exactly are you asking the community to help you with?

Comment: You're trying to instantiate [Microsoft Windows' `Shell.Application` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb776890.aspx) on the client's computer to execute your `ssh` command. This doesn't sound like what you need - do you really want to execute your `ssh` script on your web server?